# Excel formula calculation 70

Tags: excel

I am trying to come up with a formula that possibly uses the sumproduct function combined with another function.

Let me start by explaining what I have and what I want. If I have a list of 3 product numbers or more in a column, I would like excel to find the product numbers in 2 different possible columns and if they are listed there, I would like excel to multiply and sum.

I am currently using this formula:

```
=SUM(SUMPRODUCT(($B$27:$B$46='Lists for Estimates'!K2)*($E$27:$E$46*$A$27:$A$46))
+SUM(SUMPRODUCT(($F$27:$F$46='Lists for Estimates'!K2)*($I$27:$I$46*$A$27:$A$46)))
+SUM(SUMPRODUCT(($B$27:$B$46='Lists for Estimates'!K3)*($E$27:$E$46*$A$27:$A$46))
+SUM(SUMPRODUCT(($F$27:$F$46='Lists for Estimates'!K3)*($I$27:$I$46*$A$27:$A$46)))))
```

The issue with this is I have to continue to add to the formula if I add more to "Lists for Estimates." I would like to change the formula from 'List for Estimates'!K3 and K2 to search the entire column.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Create a new column on your data sheet that multiplies the A and E columns together (so the formula doesn't have to do it), and then use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF($B$27:$B$46,'Lists for Estimates'!$K$2:$K$3,$F$27:$F$46))
```

Where column F contains the multiplied values.  Adjust column F to suit your actual data.  The multiplied value column can be hidden if preferred, or even put on a different worksheet.